# How to Save .AI File so that it matches with any background

Tags: logo

A graphic designer had made a corporate logo for me in .ai but the background is white. When I open the logo in Photoshop and save it as .png, it still remains white background.

I am trying to place the logo on a grey background and want a logo that can remain transparent.

Can anyone advise how to keep a log that matches with any web based background.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your question wasn't very clear. Assuming the logo you received in .ai is indeed in vector format and not an embedded image, the background should remain transparent when opened in Photoshop. When exporting to png, the transparency option should be clicked by default.

If the designer added a literal white background in .ai you must have Illustrator or other vector software that can open .ai to remove the white background.

If on the other hand, you only want the stroke (outline) of your logo and have the fill be transparent, again you'll need a vector software to make that change. Ideally you don't do it in PS.

My best suggestion is that you contact the designer and ask them to produce png (or .tiff) of the logo *with transparent background*.